# Vue JS + Google Maps Street View API

Tags: vue.js

my system working with JQuery and not working Vue JS.

I Have Google Maps API, and i not know Write this API with Vue JS :) Please help me..

Sorry for bad English :(

This Method trigger API.

```
initmap(newLat, newLng) {
      var lat = parseFloat(newLat);
      var lng = parseFloat(newLng);
      var fenway = { lat: lat, lng: lng };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("MainGameBoard"), {
        center: fenway,
        zoom: 14
      });

      var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
        document.getElementById("MainGameMap"),
        {
          position: fenway,
          pov: {
            heading: 34,
            pitch: 10
          }
        }
      );
      map.setStreetView(panorama);
    },
```

My  API:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=API-KEY&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Where am I going to write this key? I also have to return to the function at the end.

Created? Mounted? Please help me.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you are using Vue SPA, this looks like what you need:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps

install as per the instructions in the link:

```
npm install vue2-google-maps
```

configure your main.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps'

Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
  load: {
    key: 'YOUR_API_TOKEN',
    libraries: 'places', // This is required if you use the Autocomplete plugin
    // OR: libraries: 'places,drawing'
    // OR: libraries: 'places,drawing,visualization'
    // (as you require)

    //// If you want to set the version, you can do so:
    // v: '3.26',
  },

  //// If you intend to programmatically custom event listener code
  //// (e.g. `this.$refs.gmap.$on('zoom_changed', someFunc)`)
  //// instead of going through Vue templates (e.g. `<GmapMap @zoom_changed="someFunc">`)
  //// you might need to turn this on.
  // autobindAllEvents: false,

  //// If you want to manually install components, e.g.
  //// import {GmapMarker} from 'vue2-google-maps/src/components/marker'
  //// Vue.component('GmapMarker', GmapMarker)
  //// then disable the following:
  // installComponents: true,
})
```

use in your template:

```
<template>
<GmapMap ref="mapRef" ...>
</GmapMap>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  mounted () {
    // At this point, the child GmapMap has been mounted, but
    // its map has not been initialized.
    // Therefore we need to write mapRef.$mapPromise.then(() => ...)

    this.$refs.mapRef.$mapPromise.then((map) => {
      map.panTo({lat: 1.38, lng: 103.80})
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)